# Spring alias not available when running in Grails

Tags: spring, grails

I have a problem with Spring aliases in Grails. I have a library .jar file containing classes and Spring configuration that is not working as expected. It does work as expected when I import them from a standard (no Grails) Java app.

The current configuration contains this.

```
<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
   <property name="contextPath" value="uk.co.company.package"/>
</bean>

<alias name="marshaller" alias="unmarshaller"/>
```

And fails with an error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'unmarshaller' is defined
```

Changing the configuration to the following then leads it to work as expected.

```
<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
   <property name="contextPath" value="uk.co.company.package"/>
</bean>
<bean id="unmarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
   <property name="contextPath" value="uk.co.company.package"/>
</bean>
```

The configuration is being imported and is being read. For some reason the alias is unavailable when I try to use it. What is that reason?

This is with Grails 1.3.7 and Spring 3.0.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am seeing this issue as well. You can get around it by defining the alias in the Grails resources.xml or in my case in my plugin doWithSpring closure:

```
springConfig.addAlias "aliasName", "beanName"
```

I'd expect the importBeans to import alias as well

Comment: This is what we did. It wasn't the solution I was hoping for but it works.

Answer (score 1):

This link might be helpful for you:
http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=85

It is mentioned there that aliases don't work at least when declared in the resources.xml. The post also mentions a way of declaring aliases programatically. But it seems like this post was written a while back and not sure how relevant it is with grails 1.3.7.

Comment: I found this during my pre-question googling, the first comment links it to a Jira issue http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-2222 that was fixed long ago.